# Jenkins Pipeline - Bad Substitution Error

Tags: shell, kubernetes, jenkins-pipeline

I am developing a Jenkins Pipeline to execute a JMeter Script via dynamic slaves using Kubernetes. In my pipeline under the `Get Slave Pods IP Addresses` stage, I am trying to retrieve the Pod IPs using the `kubectl` command using `jsonpath`. But during the execution it shows a `script.sh: line 1: syntax error: bad substitution`. Please help me to find out what has gone wrong in my script. Below here is my pipeline script.

```
pipeline{
    agent{
        kubernetes {
            yamlFile 'JMeter-master-pod.yaml'
        }
    }

    environment {
        JOBNAME = "jmeter-perf"
    }

    parameters {
        //Project onboarding - Set JMeter Parameters
        string(name: 'jmxFile', description: 'scriptName', defaultValue: "https")
        string(name: 'protocol', description: 'protocol', defaultValue: "testDemoScript")
        string(name: 'host', description: 'host', defaultValue: "catfact.ninja")
        string(name: 'basePath', description: 'basePath', defaultValue: "/breeds?limit=")
        string(name: 'testDataFile', description: 'testDataFile', defaultValue: "testData.csv")
    }

    stages{
        stage('Deploy JMeter Master-Slave Slaves'){
            steps{
                container ('kubehelm') {
                    sh 'echo ==================================== Start deploying JMeter [Slave] Pods ===================================='                   
                    sh 'helm repo update'
                    sh 'helm install --wait jmeter-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} --set dep.name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} custom/10-distributed-jmeter -f JMeter-slave-pods.yaml'                  
                    sh 'kubectl wait --for=condition=ready pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} --timeout=90s -n perf-platform'
                    sh 'echo ==================================== Completed deploying JMeter [Master - Slave] Nodes ===================================='
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Get Slave Pods IP Addresses') {
            steps {
                container ('kubehelm') {
                    sh 'echo ==================================== Start searching JMeter [Slave] IP Addresses ===================================='
                    script {
                        env.jenkinsSlaveNodes = sh(returnStdout: true, script:'kubectl get pods -l app.kubernetes.io/instance=distributed-jmeter-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} -n perf-platform -o jsonpath=\'{.items[*].status.podIP}\' | tr \' \' \',\'')
                    }
                    sh 'echo Slave IP Details : ${env.jenkinsSlaveNodes}'
                    sh '==================================== Finish searching JMeter [Slave] IP Addresses ===================================='
                }
            }
        }

        stage('Erase JMeter Slave Nodes') {
            steps {
                container ('kubehelm') {
                        sh 'echo ==================================== Start erasing JMeter [Slave] Pods ===================================='
                        sh 'helm uninstall jmeter-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}'
                        sh 'kubectl wait --for=condition=delete pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} --timeout=90s -n perf-platform'
                        sh 'echo ==================================== Finish erasing JMeter [Master - Slave] Nodes ===================================='
                }
            }
        }
    }

    post{
        unsuccessful {
            sh 'echo ==================================== Starting Post Failure ===================================='
            container ('kubehelm') {
                sh 'helm uninstall jmeter-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER}'
                sh 'kubectl wait --for=condition=delete pods -l app.kubernetes.io/name=jmeter-distributed-slave-${JOBNAME}-${BUILD_NUMBER} --timeout=90s -n perf-platform'
            }
            sh 'echo ==================================== Finishing Post Failure ===================================='
        }
    }
}
```

Log Error is as follows

```
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo '====================================' Start searching JMeter '[Slave]' IP Addresses '===================================='
==================================== Start searching JMeter [Slave] IP Addresses ====================================
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ kubectl get pods -l 'app.kubernetes.io/instance=distributed-jmeter-slave-jmeter-perf-23' -o 'jsonpath={.items[*].status.podIP}'
+ tr ' ' ,
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] sh
/home/jenkins/agent/workspace/jmeter-maser-slave-poc@tmp/durable-103cb96e/script.sh: line 1: syntax error: bad substitution
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // container
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Erase JMeter Slave Nodes)
Stage "Erase JMeter Slave Nodes" skipped due to earlier failure(s)
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Declarative: Post Actions)
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo ==================================== Starting Post Failure ====================================
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sh 'echo Slave IP Details : ${env.jenkinsSlaveNodes}'
```

This string is invalid.
It seems you want to use Jenkins variable here, but single quotas prevent to do this, sending string as is to sh.
And from shell syntax, variable name could not contain dot in the name.
I think you need to use double quotas here, try:

sh "echo Slave IP Details : ${env.jenkinsSlaveNodes}"